# Uncaught Error: Please provide action text with the handler

Tags: javascript, material-design

I am showing [MDC snack-bar](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/mdc-snackbar) like below. I have assigned `null` to `actionText`:

```
if(isAnyInputEmpty){
    sb.show({
        message:'Please don\'t leave '+emptyInput+' empty'
        ,actionOnBottom:false
        ,multiline:false
        ,timeout:2750
        ,actionText:null // actionText:'' => won't work too
        ,actionHandler:()=>{console.log('snackbar')}
    })
}
```

But I'm receiving this error:

> root.min.js:11 Uncaught Error: Please provide action text with the handler.

How is it possible to NOT provide an actionText for the MDC snackbar? I intend to leave it empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to comment out both `actionText` and `actionHandler` to be able to remove the snack-bar action button, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/mdc-snackbar#showing-a-message-and-action):

```
if(isAnyInputEmpty){
    sb.show({
        message:'Please don\'t leave '+emptyInput+' empty'
        ,actionOnBottom:false
        ,multiline:false
        ,timeout:2750
        /*,actionText:'Alright'
        ,actionHandler:()=>{console.log('snackbar')}*/
    })
}
```